# return the fetch() result?

Tags: javascript, return, fetch

I'm testing the fetch example from mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

My "fetchtest" function should return the google.com source code... but it isn't working.

Can you help me please?

```
console.log(fetchtest('http://google.com'));

function fetchtest(url) {
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok) {
          response.text().then(function(text) {
            //console.log(text); // is working
            return text; // isn't working
          });    
        } else {
          return 'Network response was not ok.';
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        return 'There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: You make an asynchronous request. You cannot return from it. You need to use this text right in your callback function.

Comment: if you're returning a promise that will contain the result, you're missing `return` in front of `response.text()...`